# How to create a new column in a pandas dataframe based on values from a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Can not assign proper value to the new pandas dataframe column in a loop.

I have a raw dataframe which its rows need to append to another dataframe named Feasible_Distribution_Plan.
The whole program works correctly, except for one line. To help you understand the problem, I have to write the whole code in here:

```
df = 
{'Name': {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'j', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'Type': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Number of Beams': {0: 60, 1: 60, 2: 60, 3: 60, 4: 60},
 'Number of Columns': {0: 25, 1: 25, 2: 25, 3: 25, 4: 25},
 'Total Weight': {0: 120, 1: 125, 2: 130, 3: 145, 4: 145},
 'Warehouse1 Distance to Site Location': {0: 968, 1: 447, 2: 580, 3: 245, 4: 100},
 'Warehouse2 Distance to Site Location': {0: 220, 1: 513, 2: 123, 3: 35, 4: 940},
 'Warehouse3 Distance to Site Location': {0: 215, 1: 617, 2: 319, 3: 175, 4: 228},
 'Minimum Distance to Site Location': {0: 215, 1: 447, 2: 123, 3: 35, 4: 100},
 'Date of Registeration': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Earliest Time to Deliver': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 8},
 'Latest Time to Deliver': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 11, 3: 12, 4: 9},
 'Frame Cost': {0: 3720, 1: 3875, 2: 4030, 3: 4495, 4: 4495},
 'Transportation Cost': {0: 516, 1: 1117.5, 2: 319.8, 3: 101.5, 4: 290},
 'Date of Delivery': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 8}}
```

```
current_day = 0
Charge = [250, 130, 140, 200]
Capacities = {1:{"Warehouse1":250, "Warehouse2":250, "Warehouse3":250}, 
              2:{"Warehouse1":130, "Warehouse2":130, "Warehouse3":130}, 
              3:{"Warehouse1":140, "Warehouse2":140, "Warehouse3":140},
              4:{"Warehouse1":200, "Warehouse2":200, "Warehouse3":200}}
Daily_Capacities = []
Indicator = 0
```

```
def Select_Warhouse(df, li):
    # Initialize variables
    min_col = None
    min_val = float('inf')
    results = []

    # Loop over dictionaries
    for dict_item in li:
        for key in dict_item.keys():
            # Check if key is a partial match with any column name
            matching_col = [col for col in df.columns if key in col]
            if matching_col:
                # Retrieve column name and value
                col_name = matching_col[0]
                col_val = df.iloc[0][col_name]
                results.append((col_name, col_val))
                # Update minimum value if necessary
                if col_val < min_val:
                    min_col = col_name
                    min_val = col_val
    output = [el for el in li if list(el.keys())[0] in min_col.split()[0]]
    return str(*output[0].keys())
```

```
while len(df) > 0:
    
    if current_day % 15 == 0 and current_day != 0 and Indicator == 0:
        for i, j in zip(Capacities, Charge):
            for key in Capacities[i]:
                Capacities[i][key] = Capacities[i][key] + j
    
    Indicator = 0
    
    select = df[df['Date of Delivery'] == current_day]
    if len(select) == 0:
        Daily_Capacities.append(copy.deepcopy(Capacities))        
        current_day += 1
        continue
    
    if len(select) > 1:
        Indicator = 1
        select = select[select['Total Weight'] == select['Total Weight'].max()]
    
    if len(select) > 1:
        select = select[select['Latest Time to Deliver'] == select['Latest Time to Deliver'].min()]
    
    if len(select) > 1:
        select = select.sample()
  
    Available_Warehouses = []
    for key, value in Capacities[select['Type'].iloc[0]].items():
        if select['Total Weight'].iloc[0] <= value:
                Available_Warehouses.append({key:value})
    
    if len(Available_Warehouses) == 0:
        df.loc[select.index, 'Date of Delivery'] += 1
        if Indicator == 1:
            continue        
        Daily_Capacities.append(copy.deepcopy(Capacities))
        current_day += 1
        continue
                
    elif len(Available_Warehouses) == 1:
        Warehouse = str(*Available_Warehouses[0].keys())
        
    elif len(Available_Warehouses) > 1:
        Warehouse = Select_Warhouse(select, Available_Warehouses)
                        
    Feasible_Distribution_Plan = Feasible_Distribution_Plan.append(select.iloc[0], ignore_index= True)
    Feasible_Distribution_Plan['Distance to Site Location'] = Feasible_Distribution_Plan.iloc[-1]['{} Distance to Site Location'.format(Warehouse)]
    df.drop(select.index, inplace= True)
    Capacities[select['Type'].iloc[0]][Warehouse] -= select.iloc[0]['Total Weight']
    
    if Indicator == 1:
        continue
    
    Daily_Capacities.append(copy.deepcopy(Capacities))        
    current_day += 1             

Feasible_Distribution_Plan['Date of Delivery'] = Feasible_Distribution_Plan['Date of Delivery'].astype('int32')
        
Feasible_Distribution_Plan
```

The line that is not working correctly in this last part is:

`Feasible_Distribution_Plan['Distance to Site Location'] = Feasible_Distribution_Plan.iloc[-1]['{} Distance to Site Location'.format(Warehouse)]`

What I'm looking for with this line is to create a new column in Feasible_Distribution_Plan which determine distance from the warehouse that is picked before in the loop (variable 'Warehouse' in each iteration shows that one)
I don't know much about python and pandas so couldn't sole the issue. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user19077881 Thank you for your response, but those you mentioned aren't the problem I'm facing now. In version that I'm using it is still ok to use `append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of your problem is that in each iteration, you assign `select.iloc[0]['{} Distance to Site Location'.format(Warehouse)]` to the entire `Distance to Site Location` column of your new dataframe (`Feasible_Distribution_Plan`).
You can adjust your code like this:

```
select['Distance to Site Location'] = select['{} Distance to Site Location'.format(Warehouse)].values
Feasible_Distribution_Plan = Feasible_Distribution_Plan.append(select.iloc[0], ignore_index= True)
```